# Where to find X-Ray daemon initialisation messages in Elasticbeanstalk logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-xray

Trying to monitor if the X-Ray daemon has successfully started.

There are no X-Ray daemon messages in the container logs in `eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/x.log`

Is there another log that would contain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs below describe where the X-Ray logs will be - mostly in `stdout`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html

However if you go through the EB console and download the full logs, you end up with a zip that is shaped like this (NodeJS application)

```
└── log
   ├── cfn-hup.log
   ├── cfn-init-cmd.log
   ├── cfn-init.log
   ├── cfn-wire.log
   ├── cloud-init-output.log
   ├── cloud-init.log
   ├── cron
   ├── docker
   ├── docker-events.log
   ├── eb-cfn-init-call.log
   ├── eb-cfn-init.log
   ├── eb-docker
   |  └── containers
   |     └── eb-current-app
   |        └── eb-00000-stdouterr.log
   ├── eb-docker-process.log
   ├── eb-engine.log
   ├── eb-publish.log
   ├── eb-tools.log
   ├── healthd
   |  └── daemon.log
   ├── messages
   ├── nginx
   |  ├── access.log
   |  ├── error.log
   |  └── rotated
   └── yum.log
```

From the docs one would expect `/logs/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/` to also contain an stdout log.

From the above tree view that is missing.

However we can find some x-ray service logs inside `log/eb-engine.log`. This can help to highlight if the X-Ray service is running or not.

The actual X-Ray daemon logs are posted in `/log/nessages` and can confirm if the daemon has started or now.

```
{date} {ip} systemd: Starting AWS X-Ray Daemon...
{date} {ip} systemd: Started AWS X-Ray Daemon.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find the corresponding output log path in this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-beanstalk.html) depending on how you configure the daemon on ElasticBeanstalk.

Comment: Thank you - that is what I followed and configured the EB to stream the `/var/log/xray-daemon.log` with the other EB logs. Seems like that logs is missing from the logs. This is why the question asks where can I check inside the existing log files to see if the X-Ray daemon has started.